# Rails: How to start rails server in background

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run ruby `script/server -e test`, it runs on console. When I close the console, it also stops the process. I want to run the server in the background. How can I do this?

Answer (score 26):

You can run it as a daemon with `script/server -d`

Comment: it just show first two line of => Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000

Comment: @Usman Ali: That is right. It means that the server has started. If you are on a `*nix` system, you can check whether its running by: `ps aux | grep 'script/server'`

Comment: @Swanand: i have tried it also process list is also not showing some thing. :(

Comment: It's a longshot, but perhaps you already have something running on port 3000.

Comment: @vise no, I have exactly the same problem and port 3000 is empty

Answer (score 25):

If you are using thin:

`rails server thin -d`

And, in order to stop it:

`kill -9 $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)`

Comment: Thanks! For me using puma it was: rails s Puma -d

Comment: It was ```rails server -u thin -d``` for me

Answer (score 16):

Its a bit late to answer. But it would be good for future person.

The easiest and quicker way to put rails (or any service in background) assuming it to have Unix/Linux OS

**`$ nohup rails server &`**

This can be used for any service like this

**`$ nohup <service command> &`**

Comment: Try to run in daemon mode 'nohup rails server -d &'

Answer (score 4):

Run your server with `&` at the end:

```
script/server -e test&
```

It will put it to background.

Or you can use other server like thin: http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/

```
(sudo) gem install thin
```

And then start and stop it using

```
thin start
thin stop
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this, which even stays connected on ssh is use Screen, which makes a sub terminal that isn't affected by your current console. `sudo apt-get install screen` Open screen `screen` Then start rails `rails server &`. The `&` just makes it run it the background. To stop it type `kill -9 #` where `#` is the number it gives you when you start it.

Press 'Crtl + A' to escape and type `screen -r` to get back in to the screen terminal.

Comment: Is it really professional to use `screen` for this? I feel like I should bind it to a socket and get it through my HTTPD server or something.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to use apache with passenger, it's really easy to set up and once you've done it once you can use it for all your other apps.  Plus it's most likely going to be near to what you're running on production, so that's another benefit.

If you're on a mac you can also get the passenger preference pane which simplifies the apache configuration steps.

Comment: Can we start the thin server during the start of the server.I am unable to do so.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

To add more context to [Kryptman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15141813/10907864) and oddmeter's comment.

I had this concern when trying to start a Puma rails server in background mode.

To achieve this using the `-d` flag, just run the command below:

```
rails server puma -d
```

If you want to specify a different port for the operation use the command below with the `-p` flag:

```
rails server -p 3002 puma -d
```

If you want to check the puma running server process just run the command below:

```
ps aux | grep puma
```

If you want to stop the running process, run the command below.

```
ps aux | grep puma | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill
```

OR the command below if you want to stop the process immediately. However, this is not recommended:

```
ps aux | grep puma | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9
```

**Note**: `awk` selects the second item (`$2`) in the row output which is the **PID**, while `xargs` accepts the **PID** from `awk` as an argument.

You can also achieve this with `systemd` - [Puma Systemd Configuration for Rails Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363127/10907864).