# Start ruby/rail server in background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, redmine

I am simply trying to run a ruby/rail server in background. This app contains a redmine, I use this command to run the server manually:

```
bundle exec ruby bin/rails -d server -b 192.168.0.8 webrick -e production
```

I have tried to add the & at the end to run it in an other thread but it still runs it in foreground for some reason, after looking on Google I found this: https://github.com/macournoyer/thin . But I am unsure on how to make it run all the other arguments I have after my server call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start rails server in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334403/how-to-start-rails-server-in-background)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer !

simply add the tag -d to start it as a deamon...

```
bundle exec ruby bin/rails server -d -b 192.168.0.8 webrick -e production
```