# Puma Systemd Configuration for Rails Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, server, puma

I have completed an application which was built using Ruby on Rails. Right now I want to host it on an EC2 instance on AWS.

I have provisioned a server for it, and I am using `puma` HTTP server as the application server.  Starting the application in production always requires me to run the `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` which isn't often convenient as it does not return to prompt when the application is started.

I also want to be able to manage Puma with systemd, so that I can easily `start`, `stop`, `check status` and `restart` the puma server by running a one-line command.

I have tried a lot of solutions online, but when I try to start the server I often get an error:

```
● puma.service - Puma HTTP Forking Server
   Loaded: error (Reason: Exec format error)
   Active: activating (start) since Mon 2019-12-16 15:33:06 UTC; 59s ago
Cntrl PID: 4473 (bundle)
    Tasks: 30 (limit: 4703)
   CGroup: /system.slice/puma.service
           ├─4473 puma 3.12.1 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000) [my-app]
           ├─4522 puma: cluster worker 0: 4473 [my-app]
           └─4527 puma: cluster worker 1: 4473 [my-app]

Dec 16 15:33:06 ip-172-31-19-238 rbenv[4473]: [4473] * Environment: production
Dec 16 15:33:06 ip-172-31-19-238 rbenv[4473]: [4473] * Process workers: 2
Dec 16 15:33:06 ip-172-31-19-238 rbenv[4473]: [4473] * Preloading application
Dec 16 15:33:08 ip-172-31-19-238 rbenv[4473]: [4473] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Dec 16 15:33:08 ip-172-31-19-238 rbenv[4473]: [4473] ! WARNING: Detected 1 Thread(s) started in app boot:
Dec 16 15:33:08 ip-172-31-19-238 rbenv[4473]: [4473] ! #<Thread:0x000055f4b08bf7e0@/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/a
Dec 16 15:33:08 ip-172-31-19-238 rbenv[4473]: [4473] Use Ctrl-C to stop
Dec 16 15:33:08 ip-172-31-19-238 rbenv[4473]: [4473] - Worker 0 (pid: 4522) booted, phase: 0
Dec 16 15:33:08 ip-172-31-19-238 rbenv[4473]: [4473] - Worker 1 (pid: 4527) booted, phase: 0
```

I need some help about this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Here's how I fixed it:**

1. Install [Puma](https://rubygems.org/gems/puma) if it is not already installed.
2. Run the command `which puma` to print the installation directory of the puma server on your machine, which is usually installed in `/home/your-username/.rbenv/shims/puma` directory.
3. Open the `puma.service` file located at `/etc/systemd/system/puma.service` by the running the command below:

   `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/puma.service`
4. Copy the Puma service configuration file below into it and save.

**Puma Service Configuration**

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

[Service]
# Foreground process (do not use --daemon in ExecStart or config.rb)
Type=simple

# Preferably configure a non-privileged user
User=deploy

# The path to the your application code root directory
WorkingDirectory=/home/deploy/my-app

# The command to start Puma
ExecStart=/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/puma -C /home/deploy/my-app/config/puma.rb

# The command to stop Puma
ExecStop=/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/puma -S /home/deploy/my-app/config/puma.rb

# Path to PID file so that systemd knows which is the master process
PIDFile=/home/deploy/my-app/tmp/pids/puma.pid

# Should systemd restart puma?
# Use "no" (the default) to ensure no interference when using
# stop/start/restart via `pumactl`.  The "on-failure" setting might
# work better for this purpose, but you must test it.
# Use "always" if only `systemctl` is used for start/stop/restart, and
# reconsider if you actually need the forking config.
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Note:**

- For `ExecStart`: ExecStart=/your-puma-directory-path -C /your-app-puma-config-file-path
- For `ExecStop`: ExecStop=/your-puma-directory-path -S /your-app-puma-config-file-path
- There is no need to define `ExecReload` or `ExecRestart`, they work out of the box.

You can now start the puma server using the command:

```
sudo systemctl start puma
```

OR restart the puma server using the command:

```
sudo systemctl restart puma
```

OR check the status puma server using the command:

```
sudo systemctl status puma
```

OR stop the puma server using the command:

```
sudo systemctl stop puma
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: For rails 6, I had to add env vars to make things work. In particular for the credentials key:   Environment=RAILS_ENV=...    Environment=RAILS_MASTER_KEY=...

Comment: Just stumbled on this and I know it's old but I have to object to Puma being run with root privileges, that has to be a security issue surely? That systemd file should be set in a `.config/user` location in the application users home directory and run without sudo privileges.

Comment: `systemctl enable puma.service`

Comment: some time we need wrappers gem `gem-wrappers` to get working puma executable

Comment: This is great info, but I'm getting a bunch of errors about gems: `you have already activated rack X, but your gemfile requires Y`. I've tried updating bundle, updating gems, uninstalling gems, etc. Nothing seems to work. Any ideas what to try different?